# How to Log Into a Web App Simultaneously with Different Account?

Tags: browser, login, web-application

I want to log into a web application, using at least ten account names at one single point of time ( I am not trying to do anything illegal, so don't worry). AFAIK, each tab in Chrome will share the same session, therefore, for one machine, one can use Google Chrome to log in at most 2 accounts, one in normal mode, another in [Incognito mode](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95464).

Is there anyway I can log into multiple accounts? I know I can open up IE and Firefox ( probably Safari etc) and login, but this is not really scalable as the number of web browsers is finite.

**Edit: My application is a localhost application; it resides on my computer. So proxy may not be *that* useful, and you now probably understand why it's nothing illegal.**

**Edit2: [CookieSwap](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3255) seems like a good idea, but the problem is that once I swap the cookie, all the tabs and the FF apps' cookie are swap as well. Can the swapping be done on a tab basis or on application basis, so that on a dual-monitor, I can see the different login side-by-side?**

Comment: That edit helps out a lot in figuring a solution.

Comment: shouldn't you be able to use multiple instances of Igognito?

Comment: Yeah that edit completely changes things. You should always supply as much information as possible in your question to get a more complete answer.

Comment: There can only be one instance of Incognito, in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CookieSwap](https://addons.mozilla.org/es-ES/firefox/addon/3255) to change users in just one firefox.

Comment: The problem is that once I swap the cookie, all the tabs and the FF apps' cookie are swap as well. Can the swapping be done on a tab basis?

Comment: maybe tab mix plus then https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1122

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use [**Sandboxie**](http://www.sandboxie.com/) to isolate each chrome instance by [creating new sandboxes](http://www.sandboxie.com/index.php?SandboxMenu#create).

Answer (score 2):

Use Firefox with the -no-remote option as many times you need

Problem is, you have to open several Firefox processes, the cookie swap extension seems better

Answer (score 1):

You could use multiple browsers, or I believe the "`Incognito Window`" feature in Chrome would accomplish this, too.

Comment: ...isn't that exactly what was stated in the question?

Comment: yes - but he was limiting it to *one* Incognito Window - I was trying to indicate he can use more than one

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially run browsers inside Virtual Machines (VMs) running on your system, but if you need 10 different users that's going to require an awful lot of memory so might be a non-starter.

Answer (score 0):

As it's on localhost the solution is really simple: add dummy domain names to your [`hosts`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file) file, like:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost dummy1 dummy2 dummy3
```

Or:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 dummy1
127.0.0.1 dummy2
127.0.0.1 dummy3
```

All these dummy domains will have their own cookie, and thus their own session. And the tabs or windows will be easily distinguished from one another, based on the URL you see. (Of course, this assumes the session is based on a cookie, but your testing using multiple browsers shows that is true.)

(You may also need to tell your web server to map requests for those dummy domains to the same "[virtual host](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting)".)

When this would *not* have been your own server, or one that was not easily changed to handle requests for additional domains, then using multiple web-based proxies like listed on [Privax](http://www.privax.us/) *might* do the trick as well. Though I guess I'd prefer [`-no-remote`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments) with Firefox then.