# How to maintain different active sessions in single firefox and internet explorer?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, internet-explorer, session

Suppose we are working in Firefox. Now I have opened 3 tabs. In all 3 tabs I need to work on an application e.g. gmail account. i.e. Tab 1 has Account 1, tab 2 has account2 and tab 3 has account 3. I need to do this simultaneously. Please suggest method or add-on to do this task. I also need to do the same in Internet Explorer as well.

Comment: Is this Google accounts specific or general multiple sessions ?

Comment: See "Log in with two accounts (e.g., in Gmail) in a single Firefox window" at http://superuser.com/questions/58110/log-in-with-two-accounts-e-g-in-gmail-in-a-single-firefox-window and "Firefox: Using multiple instances with different profiles?" at http://superuser.com/questions/41496/firefox-using-multiple-instances-with-different-profiles and "How to Log Into a Web App Simultaneously with Different Account?" at http://superuser.com/questions/44903/how-to-log-into-a-web-app-simultaneously-with-different-account

Comment: similar question http://superuser.com/a/352680/103134 "Is it possible to maintain two concurrent Facebook sessions in the same browser?" this question discusses how to maintain multiple user profile at once.

Answer (score 9):

The Multifox Firefox plugin may work for you: [br.mozdev.org/multifox](http://br.mozdev.org/multifox)

Comment: Specifically, the "AllAccounts" extension (previously MultiFox 2 BETA) works.

Answer (score 4):

firefox -p brings up a profile manager. you can use it to create multiple profiles.
by running "firefox -p profilename -no-remote" you can open multiple profiles at once!
therefore you can have as many logged in users in any site.
don't know about internet explorer...

Answer (score 2):

I use [Yoono](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/yoono-twitter-facebook-linkedi/) for Firefox this sort of thing.

It's designed to help out with your multiple social network accounts, but it works for any website.

After installing, you'll likely want to hide the toolbar Yoono adds (left side of the screen -> right click -> close), and then use the 'Yoono profile selector' (just left of the url) to add 3 gmail profiles, each with the same url: mail.google.com/

When you've added your profiles, you can open those profiles (with the 'Yoono profile selector') in different tabs, and enjoy browsing the same web site with different sessions in the same browser window.

The downside to Multifox Firefox, by the way, is you have to use a new window for each new session on the same web site.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
http://www.xenocode.com/browsers/

Or VMWare's ThinApp.

Both will give you a virtual environment for the browser (a thin one, not a resource hog).

Comment: The link is now http://spoon.net/browsers/.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used it, but the [GMail Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1320) addon for Firefox may help you to do this. Not sure about IE though.

**EDIT**: This obviously only helps if the application in question is GMail though!

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer 8's "Private Browsing mode" gives you a totally independent session with no shared cookies or other login details. That gets you two sessions (albeit in two different windows, rather than tabs) out of the box.

You can't do the same thing in Firefox as Firefox 3.5's "Private Browsing" mode is more of a toggle, it closes and saves your main session first.

If you have more than one user account set up on your machine you could do a Run As on Firefox to open a second (third, etc) window up as a brand new Windows user, this would get you totally independent windows with independent sessions, but again in different windows.

Comment: You can do that with Chrome too. But the problem is that you are limited to two sessions.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use [Prism](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mozilla-labs-prism/) and create a separate 'web app for each instance (login).

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do that in Internet Explorer is to do the following:

File > New Session

Then you get a new browser session, which will not use the same session as the one logged into gmail.

For Firefox use the private Browsing as others have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I do something "cheap" in Firefox - I have two GMail accounts and I keep one in a Firefox tab and a second in a Firefox tab using [IETab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1419).

But it doesn't help with *three* accounts obviously.

Answer (score 0):

Turning a website into an application using a [Site-Specific Browser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Site-specific_browser) might do the trick. For Firefox, see [Prism](https://mozillalabs.com/prism/). For a Mac, see [Fluid](http://fluidapp.com/). And Chrome has a built-in option "[Create application shortcut](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=95710)".

Answer (score 0):

You could run two (or more) entirely independent and physically differentiated instances using [Firefox Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable). Just extract the program to two (or more) locations, edit `\Other\Source\FirefoxPortable.ini` to read `AllowMultipleInstances=**True**`, and you have two functionally independent Firefox browsers.

This would not only give you discrete sessions, but the possibility of entirely different setups for different purposes.

[Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/) would probably work along the same lines as ThinApp or Browser Sandbox. People often use it to maintain a clean browser "image" that can be reset.

And I don't think the Private Tab addon was mentioned yet. It seems to create the same effect as separate private browsing windows, but in neighboring tabs.