# Firefox Add-on for Opening Pages in Separate "Sandboxes"

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, session, webpage, sandbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to maintain different active sessions in single firefox and internet explorer?](https://superuser.com/questions/60931/how-to-maintain-different-active-sessions-in-single-firefox-and-internet-explorer)

Is there a Firefox add-on that will allow someone to easily open up a page in a new tab or window so it will not share cookies and other session information with other windows?

Basically, I want to be able to run Facebook, GMail, Google Search, etc, in separate sandboxes using different accounts.

I recall seeing a blog posting about an add-on that did this without forcing you to set up different Firefox profiles, but I can't remember where I saw it or what it was called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this article](http://www.webupd8.org/2009/05/how-to-create-multiple-sessions-in.html), according to WebUpd8, you need the [CookiePie extension from Nekra](http://www.nektra.com/products/cookiepie-tab-firefox-extension).

Comment: That wasn't the one I was thinking of, but it jogged my memory enough so I could find it.  I was thinking of Multifox: http://br.mozdev.org/multifox/

Comment: @cosmic.osmo: I'm a big fan of FF myself, and that looks like one cool addon!  :-)

Comment: @Cosmic, sounds like a good answer for http://superuser.com/questions/60931/how-to-maintain-different-active-sessions-in-single-firefox-and-internet-explorer to me!