# same website - two user accounts

Tags: browser, session

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to maintain different active sessions in single firefox and internet explorer?](https://superuser.com/questions/60931/how-to-maintain-different-active-sessions-in-single-firefox-and-internet-explorer)

I have a website (vmware lab manager) that obviously stores session state.  I want to log into this site as two separate users (admin and normal user).

Are there browser tools available to connect to a website as two separate users, short of having two separate Firefox profiles (as I do now).

Comment: Web application questions are off-topic for Super User - check the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq). Until a migration path is set up you'll have to re-ask your question on the new (Web Applications)[http://webapps.stackexchange.com/] site.

Comment: ChrisF, it is fine here. The question is about a browser.

Answer (score 1):

When you open a private tab in Opera, it is totally separate thing from all other tabs and sessions.

A noteable thing is that nothing of the private tab session will be saved (no history no cookies nothing will be saved for second time use), Private session is totally temporary.

`I use to open two different gmail accounts in same window with it`

Comment: For firefox the is private browsing but it ends the current session. In Chrome you can open Incognito window to have a separate session

Answer (score 0):

You could use KeePass/LastPass to switch, if you need them at the same time you could use an IETab.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it would work, this is just a thought...

There's a way to install Firefox to a USB jump drive. If you were to install Firefox there, perhaps you can launch the local Firefox program and the USB Firefox program.

Again, I have no idea if it will work.