# PHP: Is it possible to allow login to multiple account of same site from same browser simultaneously?

Tags: php, login

I was thinking if it was possible to allow login to multiple account of the same site from same browser simultaneously .

Can this be done in php, What would be the logic involved in that case ?

I found these to related question :

[How to Log Into a Web App Simultaneously with Different Account?](https://superuser.com/questions/44903/how-to-log-into-a-web-app-simultaneously-with-different-account)

[same website - two user accounts](https://superuser.com/questions/161834/same-website-two-user-accounts)

But they don't answer my question. I want to know if it is possible on server side using php ?

Comment: your question is well asked, but the issue here is the browsers tracking and use of the session ID, which is not something you can control in server side code. if your users follow the instructions contained in your links, they will achieve your end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing preventing PHP from having multiple sessions from the same client. The issue is that *browsers* do not support receiving and sending different [session cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_%28computer_science%29#HTTP_session_token) to a single site from the same browser profile.

Comment: Yes you are right. let's see if we can have a better answer. other wise I will  accept you answer . Thanks

Comment: Then how google do it ? they have multiple logins from same browser.

Answer (score 2):

You can have multiple session simultaneously from same browser by creating multiple profiles.

For Firefox, try Multifox extension http://br.mozdev.org/multifox/
For Chrome, try https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824
IE8+ seems to have has built-in new session option

Answer (score 0):

Most modern browsers support having two sessions open, by way of Incognito or Private browsing. Internet Explorer actually allows any number of sessions by way of the File -> New Session menu item.

When you read about "Session," that is the PHP (or any other server language) way of keeping track of which browser is logged in as which user. That is why in a default configuration, for the majority of web apps, you have to use a different browser session to get a different application login.

I say the majority, because most PHP apps simply use the PHP session to tie into a web app login scenario. GMail allows you to have multiple accounts in the same browser, but only one active at a time. So, a web app could manage its own Browser Session to Application Login map, and have it be one-to-many.