# Is it possible to maintain two concurrent Facebook sessions in the same browser?

Tags: browser, facebook, session

I'm doing a lot of development with the Facebook API and it would be useful if I could be logged-in to the site with two separate accounts at the same time. Currently I use two browsers to do this, but it is something of a pain in the posterior.

I was wondering if there are any tricks I could use to do this instead, in a single browser?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It totally depends upon the browser you are using.

### Google Chrome

> 1. Copy the current **chrome.exe**'s target by going to Chrome's Properties.
> 2. Make a new shortcut and paste that copied target, make sure it is in double quotes, at last of target add **--chrome-data-dir=C:\Chrome2** press next and name that shortcut e.g. Another Chrome.
> 3. There will be a folder named Chrome2 created in **C:** partition holding your another profile :)

### Firefox

> 1. In Firefox its pretty easy to do. Right Click on Firefox's icon and go to properties.
> 2. At last of the target add **-P Firefox --no-remote** and apply the settings.
> 3. Each time you start Firefox (by clicking the shortcut you modified) you will be prompt for using profile.
>
> I have screencasted a video on this topic, [see it on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dc7mE-FnJOg%3C/p%3E)

Alternatively, if you are using browser other than mentioned above you can use Private browsing (*also known as **InPrivate Browsing** in IE and **Incognito Window** in Google Chrome*) which are quite popular on mainstream browsers, but it is recommended to specify a dedicated directory so that you don't lose your data after you quit the browser (*when using private mode you lose your data when you quit the session*)

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed instructions. Works very nicely indeed.

Answer (score 4):

Newer versions of almost all popular browsers allow you to open sites in private/incognito mode. Using this feature, you can start separate sessions in the regular & private modes.

It is called Private Browsing in Firefox (Ctrl+Shift+P) & Safari, InPrivate Browsing (Ctrl+Shift+P) in IE9+, Incognito window in Chrome (Ctrl+Shift+N).

IE8+ has an option called New Session under the File menu that you can use to handle two different sessions of the same site

Comment: Many thanks for the info. Works really well and is going to save me much hair-tearing. I'm accepting @Santosh's because of his additional tips.

Comment: one con I find in this method is: when you quit the browser, you will lose all your browsing data (including cookies, cache etc.). Specifying a dedicated directory for holding the profile gives you freedom from sessions. You can continue even after shutting down.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add instructions for **Opera**:

```
opera -pd ~/.opera2
```

will start an independent session with session directory `~/.opera2`.

Opera, as do Chrome, also supports incognito mode by pressing Ctrl+Shift+N, but this will come with the drawback that one cannot reopen closed tabs.